# Custom ELF sections for attaching stringy metadata

Tags: linux, gcc, elf

I would like to be able to associate some stringy, easily-extractible key-value pairs with my ELF executables.

I've noticed gcc-compiled ELFs have a `.comment` section

```
$ readelf -p .comment a.out
```

So I tried to replicate that:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){ puts("Hello world"); return 0; }
const char str[] __attribute__((section(".meta"))) = "hello meta world";
```

Test:

```
$ readelf -p .meta a.out 
String dump of section '.meta':
  [     0]  hello meta world
```

or

```
 $ readelf -p .meta a.out | sed -n 's/^[^]]*]  //p'
   hello meta world
```

This works.

Is there a better way to attach such stringly key-value pairs to an ELF file (without breaking it down to multiple files)? Is there a namespace (e.g. `.user.meta`) for user sections that would prevent me from breaking something?

Comment: What do you need those? Do you need them at runtime?

Comment: @ysdx No. It's completely inessential but I thought it would be nice if I had a way of quickly extracting `whatis`-style kind of info out of lone scripts and binaries of mine (without relying on them consistently accepting `--help` switches or having `man` pages).

Answer (score 3):

According to the [spec](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/elf.pdf), all dot-prefixed section names are reserved and user sections without the dot prefix are safe to use:

> Section names with a dot ( . ) prefix are reserved for the system,
>   although applications may use these sections if their existing
>   meanings are satisfactory. Applications may use names without the
>   prefix to avoid conflicts with system sections. The object file format
>   lets one define sections not in the list above. An object file may
>   have more than one section with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Also, the Linux kernel uses this trick frequently (usually via inline assembly and `.pushsection` directives) to store frequently accessed or important data structures (usually arrays of structs).  It has non-standard ELF sections such as __ex_table and __fixup.